# When target object index all other objects indexes changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Briefy, I don't know how to explain it by words so here is the code.

I store the below object as global object in `window` like this`

**Code :** `window.builder.blocks_schema['section-${active_section_uid}']['block-${active_block_uid}']`

**Object example:**
`{blocks_schema: Array(0)}
blocks_schema: Array(0)
section-1576017484592:
block-1576017486329: {base: "newsletter", desc: "", atts: Array(1)}
block-1576017486673: {base: "newsletter", desc: "", atts: Array(1)}
block-1576017486920: []`

The problem is when I want to modify something in a `block-...` I use :

**(1)** `window.builder.blocks_schema['section-${active_section_uid}']['block-${active_block_uid}'] = []`

and only the index with `active_section_uid` and `active_block_uid` changes everything is ok until now.

But when I want to modify `atts` in `block-...` all blocks `atts` changes in same time.!!!

**(2)** `window.builder.blocks_schema['section-${active_section_uid}']['block-${active_block_uid}'].atts =[]`

like you see in above object `block-1576017486920` is empty as result of code **(1)**, but using code **(2)** leads to all blocks `atts` equal empty array however I only targeted `block-1576017486920`

Comment: If you make a reproducible example using https://jsfiddle.net/ or something similar, you might get more help. It's hard to say what is happening with what you posted.

Comment: @tcigrand thank you for your time, but this code is part of another little bit big code and depends on other codes to work is hard to reproduce it on jsfiddle